# Find units with zero categories

Tags: sql, mysql

I am after an SQL command to find units with no categories. Here are the tables:

**Unit**

```
id  name
```

**UnitCategory**

```
id  name
```

**UnitCategoryIndex**

```
id  categoryid  unitid
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check the syntax (i wrote it for SQL Server).

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM Unit as u
LEFT JOIN UnitCategoryIndex as uci
ON u.id = uci.UnitId
where uci.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM Unit WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UnitCategoryIndex WHERE Unit.id = UnitCategoryIndex.unitid)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from unit U
 where not exists ( select *
                      from unitcategoryindex X
                     where X.unitid = U.id
                  )
```